# PHP and Shortcode Combination

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I would like to display the social locker WordPress plugin around a custom field.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker]'.$to_lock.'[/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

Here is my custom field:

```
<?php the_field('link'); ?>
```

Social locker requires a open and close shortcode:

```
[sociallocker id="16619"]
[/sociallocker]
```

The following does not work correctly:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="16619"]'); ?>
<?php the_field('link'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

Comment: Use `get_field` with your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the shortcode with the field value just before you evaluate it with do_shortcode.

the_field('link') will automatically output the value while get_field('link') will return the value.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker]'. get_field('link') . '[/sociallocker]');?>
```

The problem you had before is that your evaluating the first 1/3 which doesn't include the data. Then you print the data. And again evaluate a close tag without data.